# delay between server and client when download a file with lighttpd+php

Tags: php, file, delay, lighttpd, transfer

I wrote a php script which is send a large file (1GB more) to http client. 
When The server-side write a log that 'file transfer is finished'(lighttpd accesslog and my own php log) when finish sending, client-side still progressing download. 
I called ob_flush() and flush() after the last segment sent.
But the running time difference between server and client is about several ten seconds.
 
My test environment informations are:
    - Server & client is connected with same local gigabit switch
    - redhat 6.4, lighttpd 1.4.28, php 5.3.3
    - sysctl parameter in server-side is:
    net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096    16384   4194304
     net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096   16384   4194304
    - php.ini buffer size is:
          memory_limit = 16M

How can I reduce finish-time gap between server and client?

Answer (score 1):

lighttpd reads the output of CGI as fast as it can so that the CGI can finish processing and free up resources.  Many CGI script instances running in parallel often use much more memory than does a single lighttpd process.

The default behavior in lighttpd is to buffer the entire response before sending to the client, and for a local producer and remote client, the local production can be much faster than network.  For LANs, the opposite may be true, especially when the producer (backend CGI) is slow.

In lighttpd 1.4.40 and later, you can set `server.stream-response-body = 1` in lighttpd.conf and lighttpd will attempt to stream the response to the client as it received it from the backend CGI.  lighttpd 1.4.40+ will still buffer to disk if the backend sends the response faster than lighttpd can send it to the network.  If you want lighttpd 1.4.40+ to perform minimal buffering (and potentially block the backend producer if the client or network is slower than the producer), you can set `server.stream-response-body = 2`